# NSManagedObject is not fault but app crashing on accessing it on backgroung thread

Tags: swift, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobject, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am facing an issue in which NSManagedObject is not showing issues on MainThread but on accessing same NSManagedObject in background thread, it is showing error:
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

I actually not having any idea that why it is happening.

I am fetching this NSManagedObject by mainContext using peform{} block method.
So this returned object works fine on main thread but on accessing this object in background thread, i am getting crash.

I don't know clearly that what extra information should I provided to describe my problem.

If anyone have any idea about my problem, then let me know about this.

Comment: Have you tried to create a child NSManagedObjectContext in the background thread and retrieve NSManagedObject from it?

Comment: No Artem, actually I am doing reverse of it. I am fetching NSManagedObject from main thread using main context (mainQueueConcurrencyType) and then trying to using this NSManagedObject in background thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed objects (and contexts) can only be accessed from specific threads. If you want to access a managed object from a background thread you need to create a context with private queue concurrency, and then use the `performBlock:` method.

```
let bgContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: privateQueueConcurrencyType)
bgContext.perform {
    // code which accesses managed object
}
```

If you need to take a specific entity from the main thread and access it in the background, you can take the object's `managedObjectID` from the main thread and then call `existingObject(with:)` in the background block to get the same entity in the background context.

Comment: If I am able to get the private queue contexted NSManagedObject, am I restricted to only use it within the await backgroundContext.perform block? I am having threading crashes on the next line after the perform block even though I am excepting the whole code inside an async function which I have confirmed is background thread.